# Portraying quarter circle symbology with multiple attributes in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology

I have four columns, (A, B, C, D) and each can be ranked 1, 2, or 3 (point data).

I would like to portray each category at once based on colors assigned to the rankings (1 = green, 2 = yellow, 3 = red).

I am imagining this would look like a pie chart with four quarters, and each quarter would be colored based upon the ranking.

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using ArcGIS Desktop...

You can symbolize based on multiple attributes but it is limited to 3 fields not 4. The quickest thing I would do is to create a new field and just concatenate fields A,B,C, and D to give you a code. This would give you data like

`1121
2311
3312`
 and so on. Then you would just have to symbolize each ... nevermind that is way too many combos...

---

Make 4 definition queries on the data. You will produce 4 layers, 1 layer for each field. Ex: layer_A, layer_B, layer_C, layer_D. Create a custom symbol that is 1/4 of a circle for each layer. Top left, top right, bottom right, bottom left.  Symbolize each layer based on the ranking 1,2,3 to change the color of that quadrant.

Simple square example with offsets
[image: circle]

Custom pie circle symbols

[image: square]

Circle template (click reverse foreground/background) rotate by 90 degrees 3 times to get the full circle)

[image: circle template]

Comment: ArcGis also does pie charts and bar graphs which, depending on the type of data and the expectation of the user, might be more suitable. Generally the charts and graphs are OK but I always end up converting them to graphics and moving them around for a finished map product.

Comment: How do you convert to graphics? I created the four layers and offset the symbols as squares to form a 4x4 grid, colors represented by the 1-3 ranking. I would like to move them since there is some overlap in some places. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should be able to get them to line up without it. I was able to get the simple square to line up. I think I used 15 pt with 7.5 offsets (ArcMap just crashed so I can't confirm). If you have to convert to graphics, just right click the layer and selecct "convert to graphics". Adding pics to answer.

Answer (score 3):

This question has come up again in [a duplicate](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234050/add-quarter-circle-symbology-into-arcmap?noredirect=1#comment364984_234050) but more information has come to light. There are character marker symbols representing the 4 quadrants of a circle in ESRI IGL Font22, unicode chars 122 to 125 inclusive:

[image]

To render this layer with 4 quadrants based on attributes A, B, C and D I would replicate the layer so that there is 4 layers with 3 combinations:

[image]

[image]

and so on...

Only 3 symbols to edit for each layer, that's only 12 edits. If you try to render all combinations of 4 fields in one layer that's potentially *a lot* of combinations to manually enter.

Here's how it looks in ArcMap:

[image]

I've used a black background so that the yellow is clear. Points were just some random data with A, B, C and D fields added and calculated to `random.randint(1,3)`.

Comment: Very useful simple answer!